# Uploading csv files to an R file without having excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, r, csv

I'm starting an internship where I'll be uploading different csv files into some R files I'm working on. Problem is, I don't have excel and can't really pay for Microsoft Office. Are there any options, such as excel online or a read only excel file that I'll still be able to upload it to the R file?

Comment: I’m not the down voter, but you should really make an effort at searching for an answer before giving up and ask here. A simple Google search would have provided an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the R function `read.csv()`.

Comment: Even the simplest of Google searches would have figured this out. http://rprogramming.net/read-csv-in-r/